# PayPal NVP header image (HDRIMG)

Tags: image, paypal, header, nvp

I'm using the [PayPal NVP](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/) to manage the client payments on my site.
Recently I noticed that the image that goes on the header of the PayPal paying platform appears to be cut (before the size was 750x90, and now seems to be 535x90).

The field that puts the image on the header [HDRIMG](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/set-express-checkout-nvp/?mark=HDRIMG#deprecated-fields) is now deprecated since Septembre 2016 (yeah I know im late), and I can't find any official replacement for this.

How is the new method/param to put an image on the header? or it is obsolete and should be deleted?

[image: Image where you can see the actual size of the image and what it shows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDRIMG is obsolete, there is LOGOIMG

These days most new integrations use an "in context" checkout that keeps their site loaded in the background and open PayPal in a small window.

This way, you don't need branding on PayPal because your site essentially stays loaded.

You can see some demo code here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

(The same UI can be paired with NVP or the new REST APIs using the server version: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server )